# Rendering a chart.js component twice in a page

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have a component which builds a stacked bar chart which I need to call twice on some other page with different data. While I'm trying to do that, both the charts are getting rendered but they are overlapping each other.

Chart component html file is like

```
    <mat-card >
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
                <mat-icon class="iconText">developer_board</mat-icon>
                <b class="iconText">{{title}}</b>
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="ch">
               <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
                <!-- <svg width="400" height="300"></svg> -->
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

and my component.ts file is

```
var chartEle=(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myChart")).getContext("2d")
  this.chart = new Chart(chartEle, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: this.formatInputDataToChartData(), //function to generate dataset
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
        yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
      }
    }
  });
```

The parent component looks like

```
<div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <div fxFlex="50">
        <app-bar-chart [data]="appBarChartData" [title]="appChartTitle"></app-bar-chart>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50" >
        <app-bar-chart [data]="dbBarChartData"  [title]="dbChartTitle"></app-bar-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use:

```
var chartEle=(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myChart")).getContext("2d")
```

Just define a canvas in your component template and then use @ViewChild to get a reference to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  template: `
    <div>
      <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>`,
})

@ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
this.ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {...
```